# Anaconda5.0.1 install on linux fails due to permission denied error on python3.6

Tags: linux, permissions, installation, anaconda

First time question here so please be gentle:)

I'm setting up Anaconda5.0.1 with Python3.6 on Ubuntu 17.x and at the point of starting to install all the packages I get a Permission Denied error when the install script (line 355) tries to execute Python3.6 in the anaconda3/.../bin folder. It seems that the extracted python3.6 does not end up with execute permission on it and hence the error.

i) I tried the install on virtual box (different machine) with ubuntu 14.x and it did extract python3.6 with the execute permission and so ran fine.

ii) Back on the ubutunu 17.x install I checked umask and it returned 0022 which should be a problem.

iii) I downloaded and installed the python2.7 version on the ubuntu 17.x machine and same permission issue.

I'm new to ubuntu admin so not sure what else to explore ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. First, check if you have **read** and **execution** permissions in all the parent folders of the anaconda3 folder. If you don't, add the permissions with `chmod a+x folder`. Avoid add permissions to system-protected folders.

If you are installing anaconda in a disk other than where / is mounted, also check `/etc/fstab` to be sure that the disk is mounted with the `exec` option.